# How to create multiple app NodeJS cluster?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, cluster-computing

I need direction on how to best setup an environment that can scale to host as many as 20-50 NodeJS applications. Each application is independent of each other for different corporate needs. Each application should be accessible via a standard URL on the internal network (port 80).

Our corporate infrastructure is very strong and I have the ability to spin up as many servers as I need (running as many cores, as much RAM and HD space that I need - zero limitations).

My understanding is that I'll need a web server of some sort to act as a reverse proxy. But for the app server(s) should I have one really decked out server? many so-so spec'd servers? Should I limit each app server to something like 5-10 apps per?

Should each app run on its own instance of NodeJS or should I have one huge clustered instance that runs many apps? If clustered, I read concerns that I can't leverage session - will that impact O365 authentication?

Thanks!

Comment: Use NGINX as the proxy to split your apps on port 80 based on URL path to each separate node.js app each running on its own local port and perhaps own host.  What you need to do to scale each individual nodejs app depends entirely upon their own individual load and design.  This is not something you likely do the same for all of them.

Comment: If your nodejs apps are separate independent apps as you say, then they have to each run their own nodejs instance.  That's how they are written.

Comment: There's no way we can tell you how many apps per host.  You might be able to have 50 apps on one host or you might need a 10 cluster host for one app.  It totally depends upon the design and load of each individual app.

Comment: So you're saying spin up a NGINX server as a balancer and a single APP server for the apps. As I deploy apps, monitor their demand and when the APP server starts getting heavy-ish load, spin up another app server and repeat?

Comment: Should each app (nodejs process) have cluster enabled?

Comment: If by "app server", you mean a physical server to run nodejs apps, then yes.  But, I rather doubt you want 20-50 apps. all clustered.  So, when you add a new host, you would examine the load each is under and manually assign some apps to the new host.

Comment: No.  You don't want each server app clustered because each server that is clustered has to be designed specifically for that as either entirely stateless or with all state available from some central resource (such as a database).  Even login sessions are complicated by clustering.  So, the only apps that should be clustered are the ones that individually need more than one host to support their scale and then they have to be specifically designed to support clustering.

Comment: By app server I do mean the physical/VM server. I think I get where you going and this helps me out a lot. I'll start out small with the single balancer and host for the apps. Small apps will be single threaded and larger more demanding apps will be clustered. Once all the CPU threads (or RAM) are 70-80% consumed I'll spin another host server up for new apps.

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea.  Just keep in mind that node.js servers (or really any server) don't necessarily cluster automatically from the outside without being designed to be clustered in their code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PM2 to run you nodejs APPS in the server in fork mode or clustered mode based on the requirement.

These apps can be accessed by different PORTS, Use Nginx and create server blocks for each of your apps and add the proxy pass to the respective ports.